# Set button variable based on loaded view/url using Djangos Template Language? Python

Tags: python-2.7, django-templates

In my `base.html` template I have a link to a website that I would like displayed at the top of each page that extends it:

```
base.html
<a href='websiteOne' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Results</a>
```

Except for `results.html`, when I load that page I would like the link loaded as:

```
results.html
<a href='websiteTwo' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Home</a>
```

I'm under the impression that the template language could solve my problem with an `if` statement:

```
if currentTemplate/urlRoute != results.html:
    button = <a href='websiteOne' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Results</a>
else:
    button = <a href='websiteTwo' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Home</a>
```

Please help point me in the right direction to implement this if possible :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current URL in template by using `request.path`. The `request` variable automatically gets passed into each template context if you use Django's RequestContext as recommended (you probably do, since it's the default way).

Then you can just do `{% if "reports" in request.path %}......{% endif %}`.

That said, a cleaner approach would be to put the link in your base.html in a `{% block %}` template tag, like this:

```
{% block top_link %}<a href='websiteOne' class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Results</a>{% endblock %}
```

Then this URL will be the same in all the pages, and you will be able to override it in your reports page by just specifying another content for the block.